# What does Jared Diamond's theory say?

Tags: political-theory, history

I am asking about [Jared Diamond's (smallpox) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel). What does the theory really say? Does it mention whether specific genes were involved or if it is a theory of racial superiority?

Comment: In point of fact, a widespread disease *can* favor genetic adaptations that help prevent it (this is thought to be one of the causes of higher rates of sickle-cell disease in much of Africa, for instance, since the same mutation that causes it also protects against malaria in individuals with a single copy). As this examples shows, one does not end up superior or inferior, but rather experiences a tradeoff. However, in the case of smallpox, the major factor seems to have been a lack of *acquired* immunity (through previous infection or antibody transfer during pregnancy or lactation).

Comment: Have you read *Guns, Germs, and Steel*? It is easily available in libraries or for sale.

Comment: The Question is not that bad. Yes, it can be answered by carefully reading the book, but so are quite a deal of e.g. quantum mechanics questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much racial anything as the fact that populations in some areas had had recurring exposure to smallpox. Smallpox was quite deadly and very catchy and for people whose ancestors had never developed resistance it wiped out a lot of people very quickly. Even Europeans had about 25-30% mortality rate from it and they had a background of their ancestors having had exposure (and survived). The genes? Who knows? Even without genetic theory the idea that some groups don't react well to novel diseases would have been noticed at the time.

Here's a not too bad write up about [the conquest of Mexico](https://theconversation.com/how-smallpox-devastated-the-aztecs-and-helped-spain-conquer-an-american-civilization-500-years-ago-111579).  IIRC about 80-90% of the native population died within a few decades of Spanish landing.

And that's before one gets into whether or not smallpox was intentionally brought into contact with natives (there have been clear-cut cases when it was, there have been claims that are less proveable).

Jared Diamond took this, among other observations, and wrote up a fairly engaging book that, yes, can easily be brought up whenever people discuss why the world is politically organized the way it is.

His theory does have political implications and is basically that pretty much everything in world civilizations is the result of geographic determinism ("better endowed areas made out better").  According to the part of Diamond's theory relating to diseases, Europe was "lucky" to have learned to put with so much disease burden and when Europeans expanded into areas with less historical disease, they benefited from the fact many many people they came into contact with got sick.

To quote wikipedia:

> The book attempts to explain why Eurasian and North African civilizations have survived and conquered others, while arguing against the idea that Eurasian hegemony is due to any form of Eurasian intellectual, moral, or inherent genetic superiority. Diamond argues that the gaps in power and technology between human societies originate primarily in environmental differences, which are amplified by various positive feedback loops. When cultural or genetic differences have favored Eurasians (for example, written language or the development among Eurasians of resistance to endemic diseases), he asserts that these advantages occurred because of the influence of geography on societies and cultures (for example, by facilitating commerce and trade between different cultures) and were not inherent in the Eurasian genomes.

Diamond's overall theory, not just disease, is not perfect though:  Japan should not have done well at all, as per Diamond's recipes.

The problem is that Diamond pretty much does his best to downplay aspects that come from people's culture, rather than their geography (caveat:  see phoog's comment below).  So that a culture places a high value on education doesn't matter.  Ditto a better or worse governed society.

**According to Diamond: it's all in the geography.**

But it is a thought provoking book (the paragraphs above are *slight* criticism, my opinion is still largely positive).

and... to address the question, it is pretty much the opposite of a book claiming racial superiority.

Comment: "Diamond pretty much does his best to ignore any aspect that comes from people's culture, rather than their geography": Diamond discusses China's decision not to pursue seafaring imperialism, which was not geographical and was, arguably at least, cultural, as an illustration of the impact cultural factors can have.

Comment: Who is Monica that so many people mention in their user names?

Comment: @JosephP. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393046/who-or-what-is-monica-and-why-so-much-notice-from-se-users

Answer (score -1):

There was a one gigantic difference between the 'new' (Americas) and 'old' world: **domesticatable animals**.  It turns out the vast majority of animals cannot be domesticated, and almost all only existed in the old world (only real exception being llamas, which are far less adaptable than cows, sheep, pig, etc).

Because of this, old world and new world societies were built in very different ways.  A primary difference is that in the old world you had people living in fixed locations in close proximity to dirty animals.  It turns out that plague viruses, like smallpox, are almost always initially viruses that affect some particular domesticatable animal.  And as we all have recently seen, animal viruses can mutate in ways that make them able to infect humans.  And while the viruses previously barely affected the animals, things like smallpox absolutely destroy naïve human immune systems.

You can see where this is going: human and animal populations in Europe and China greatly increased in population and density (in part because they had such ready access to animals!), and with so many more infections occurring between animals you have a much better chance of seeing crossover mutations.  People with genetics that make them more susceptible to such disease die out (this is obviously simplified), and from evolution we end up with populations in the old world whose immune systems are extremely good at fighting such disease.

So it ends up being quite simple: new world populations didn't live near animals so there were no unique plague virus in the Americas and the opposite was true in the old world.  So when the exchange happens it's new-world indigenous populations getting hit with literally 1000's of years of different plagues at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

In his book, Diamond points out again and again how various successful expansions (including but not limited to the European conquest of the Americas) can be explained sufficiently by looking only at the geographical and biological (specifically the presence or absence of certain types of plants and animals in a certain geographical area) features of the region where the expanding culture began. He is careful to state time and time again that these expansions were absolutely not a consequence of racial superiority.

In fact, he goes a step further and downplays even the contributions of specific inventors or explorers; arguing for example that inventions which greatly aided expansion and subjugation of other cultures were bound to come up sooner or later once the necessary conditions came together. Likewise, *any one* European state was bound to finance an exploration party westwards at some point in the late 15th century; the fact that it was Columbus who set sail and the Spanish crown that sent him was a historical accident. It might as well have been an English, French, Italian, Danish or other King and pretty much any other sailor.

Going deeper into the Columbus example, he further argues that the geography of Europe, allowing for many similarly strong, competing states, favoured this outcome (an explorer whose trip is financed by a royla house) over East Asia where one single kingdom had emerged controlling essentially the entire well-equipped geographical region (China). In China's case, it all depended on a single monarch who had little to fear while if the Spanish king had said no maybe the French king would have said yes and so on.

When it comes to diseases, the key (geographic and biological) factor is again not genetic but exposure. Smallpox had been raging in Europe for a while to the point where most of the adult population would be made up of smallpox survivors and the survival of a child would depend on (among others; but I'm simplifying and exaggerating here) whether it survived smallpox or not. This led to a relatively low smallpox death rate among adults. However, Europe was not the only part of the Old World with endemic smallpox: the same is true for Africa and Asia, meaning that when Europeans arrived there the population was as exposed to smallpox as they were. Conversely, there is no historical evidence for smallpox having existed in the Americas prior to Columbus, so once that necessarily travelled across the pond as a stowaway it could wreck havoc on the unexposed population, infecting not just the young and very few adults but all.

On the other hand, the tropics are well-known to be home to malaria while Europe itself is not. So European explorers reaching (e.g.) the African coast would suddenly become exposed to malaria in a way they would not be back at home; therefore, the colonisation of Africa was necessarily delayed as even though Europeans had the guns and steel advantages Africa still had the germs advantage.

Throughout his book, Diamond doesn't really point to any specific genes. In fact, with a few limited exceptions (such as the ability to digest lactose or alcohol tolerance) few advantages of societies can be traced back to single genes – and in the smallpox case, they certainly can't.

Note, by the way, that it does not matter to Diamond's central claim whether smallpox was purposely introduced (as has happened in some, documented cases) or whether it was accidentally brought along (as with the Columbian voyages).